# install in subdomain with Joomla

Tags: joomla

we are moving from an access database to civcrm shortly.  I have decided to load it on a subdomain.  our public website is joomla based, so it probably makes most sense to stick with that. so loading joomla and having civicrm installed as the only component on the subdomain installation.

That being said,  should the sub domain files be loaded in the public_html folder or just in the home folder?

We want to keep the civcrm info private and i will be likely using the api to get data to the public site or performing some scheduled export from civicrm import into data table for extentions procedure we already have in place for showing events etc.

Does it matter?  I dont think it should but first timer here!  lol

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a web server configuration question than CiviCRM-specific.  Having a subdomain (that is, civi.mysite.org, not mysite.org/civi) doesn't even require the sites be on the same server, let alone in a directory of another.

I recommend a complete separation of their folders (assuming non-crappy hosting that doesn't make this difficult/impossible).  When placing a CMS inside another CMS's folder, you can end up in scenarios where files that shouldn't be web-readable become web-readable.

Comment: Thanks.  I did make the move and created a subdomain with a separate install of Joomla.